# bash regular expression test: if vs grep

Tags: regex, bash

I need to scan each line of a file looking for any characters above hex \x7E.  The file has several million rows, so improving efficiency would be great.  So far, reading each line in a while loop, this works and finds lines with invalid characters:

```
echo "$line" | grep -P "[\x7F-\xFF]" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then...
```

But this doesn't:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ [\x7F-\xFF] ]]; then...
```

I'm assuming it would be more efficient the second way, if I could get it to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: What are you doing if you find them? A tool like `sed` might be more efficient than looping through rows in bash if you're doing simply substitution.

Comment: I basically have to split the file.  Valid records go to one file, invalid records go to another.  Also, what I'm testing is a subset of an existing script that I have to modify once I figure out what the best solution is.

Comment: Scanning a file with several million lines will be far faster in a language like Python than using shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in efficiency, you shouldn't write your loop in bash. You should rethink your program in terms of pipes and use efficient tools.

That said, you can do this with

```
LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C
if [[ "$line" =~ [$'\x7f'-$'\xff'] ]]
then 
    echo "It contains bytes \x7F or up"
fi
```

Comment: +1 Believe this should work. Any specific reasons of using `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE` ?

Comment: That works, thank you!  I'd agree about reworking the program, but I don't have that luxury.  I have to inject this bit into an existing script.  Thanks again...

Comment: One more comment:  the "if" version is about 6-7 times faster than the pipe-to-grep version, so thanks again!

Comment: @whafrog To put that into perspective, on my system the `while-read-if` version is 2500 times slower than running grep on the stream itself, taking 25.5s vs 0.01s for 10k lines.

Comment: Yes, I tried glenn jackman's pure grep below, and I'm strongly urging a revision.  We'll see how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

> I basically have to split the file. Valid records go to one file, invalid records go to another.

```
sed -n '/[^\x0-\x7e]/w badrecords
        //!          w goodrecords'
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's more I have to do in the loop based on what's in the record.  I really just need to know why the if-regex version doesn't work while the grep does.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Perl regular expressions, you might as well use perl for the task:

```
perl -ne '
    if (/[\x7F-\xFF]/) {print STDERR $_} else {print}
' file > valid 2> invalid
```

I'd bet that's faster than a bash loop.

I suspect this would be more efficient, even though it processes the file twice:

```
grep  -P "[\x7F-\xFF]" file > invalid
grep -vP "[\x7F-\xFF]" file > valid
```

---

You'd want to write your grep code as

```
if grep -qP "[\x7F-\xFF]" <<< "$line"; then...
```

Comment: Thanks, but as said above this bit is being put into a larger script that can't be revised in that way.  If we get a chance to rewrite it I'll keep these in mind.